# Copying a MySQL search query into a Data table

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, datatable

I am having trouble getting the data inside a DataTable into a DataGridView. I found code in Visual Basic and tried translating it into Visual C++.

```
        String^ cninfo = "server=localhost; port=3306; username=test; password=Lalala123; database=turismo";
        MySqlConnection^ cn = gcnew MySqlConnection;
        MySqlDataAdapter^ cmdadp;
        DataTable^ Table = gcnew DataTable;

        String^ search = searchtxt->Text;
        int^ rowposition = 0;
        String^ id_searchQuery = ("select * from clientes where CLIENT_ID = @search;");
        String^ name_searchQuery = ("select * from clientes where FIRST_NAME like '%@search%';");
        String^ lastname_searchQuery = ("select * from clientes where LAST_NAME like '%@search%';");
        String^ origin_searchQuery = ("select * from clientes where COUNTRY_ORIGIN like '%@search%';");

        if (radid /*Radbutton for id_searchQuery*/->Checked == true) {

            cn->ConnectionString = cninfo;
            cn->Open();

            //defining parameters for the search query
            MySqlCommand^ searchCmd = gcnew MySqlCommand(id_searchQuery, cn);
            searchCmd->CommandType = CommandType::Text;
            searchCmd->Parameters->AddWithValue("@search", search);

            //filling the DataTable with MySqlDataAdapter
            cmdadp->Fill(Table);

            //counting each DataTale line to enter it into a DataGridView with a while function
            while (rowposition < Table->Rows->Count) {

                DataRow^ MyDataRow = Table->Rows(rowposition);

            }
            cn->Close();

        }
```

On `(rowposition < Table->Rows->Count) {` i get the "<" highlighted and i get

> No operator "<" matches these commands

And on `DataRow^ MyDataRow = Table->Rows(rowposition);` i get highlighted "Table" and i get

> call of an object of a handle type without apropriate operator () or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type

Comment: What happens if you just declare `rowposition` as an `int` rather than `int^`?

Comment: first error with the operator gets fixed but second error gets nothing

Comment: `Table->Rows` is of type [DataRowCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).  Try accessing the row using the `Item` property array notation, e.g., `Table->Rows[rowposition]`.

Comment: LoL - glad to help :-)

Comment: how do i close the question now?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Comment: I see, then ill just copy your answer then.

Comment: I wasn't sure either since I haven't closed a question.

I'm not sure if you can (your abilities depend on your reputation score), but *if* you can, would you mind up-voting the comments where I answered so that I get a reputation bump.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: sorry, this is my first question in this community and i dont see any upvote button. Else i would :). But sorry i cant.

Comment: That's OK no worries.  Glad we made some progress on your problems in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just declare rowposition as an int rather than int^?

Table->Rows is of type DataRowCollection Class. Try accessing the row using the Item property array notation, e.g., Table->Rows[rowposition]

answered by @Phil Brubaker